# Installing NVIDIA graphics Driver

Tags: installation, drivers, nvidia, graphics

How to stop X server before installing Nvidia graphics Driver in Ubuntu 13.10

Answer (score 0):

**You don't need to do this to install Nvidia driver.**

Anyway, if you really want to do this, go in tty1 by typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and run the following command:

```
sudo service lightdm stop
```

To start it again:

```
sudo service lightdm start
```